# should I do task definition for nginx and nodejs seperate or together?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I want to up four nodejs containers and one nginx container on my ec2 with ecs.

So I know that I need to create task definition for nodejs image, and service to run this task.

In the service I set number of tasks to 4. so now in my ec2 I run four nodejs containers.

but I want to add nginx. if I add to this task nginx container, did it duplicate nginx containers four times like nodejs containers?

Or should I create a task definition for nodejs and another task definition for nginx, and run in service two tasks, nodejs-task four times and nginx-task one time?

Which approach is correct?